# VBscript to compare contents of some of the columns in two excel sheets for a given row

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am new to VBscripting so please bear with me. I have two sheets which represents an old database and a new database with following structure

```
A          B(key)      C       D      E       F
```

837 |   15287RI0300002 | Individual | SelectRI | Direct | New Plan

```
A          B(key)      C      D      E       F      G      H
```

837 |   15287RI0300002 | Individual | Rating1 | Rating2 | SelectRI | Direct | New Plan

I have to compare the contents of a row according to the key and highlight the differences. Now the problem is that columns are not ordered. Thus I need a mapping from one sheet to another.

Can anyone help me with a vbscript ? Please try to give a general solution as I have multiple worksheets in the workbook.

P.S.

1. Rows are not sorted
2. The sheets are in separate workbook
3. It is not necessary that key in old sheet always exist in new sheet.

Comment: Are the column headers identical in the worksheets as you have shown? Do you need the code to iterate over all rows or just be called on specific rows?

Comment: Not all column headers are identical and I need to iterate over all rows in the first sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns in the old and new DB are not identical, the mapping needs to be written by you. One possibility would be to make a table in a separate worksheet where you specify which column corresponds to which other. Kind of hard to maintain, switching sheets all the time and checking.

Another possibility would be to insert a row right at the top of the sheet of the new DB and write the names of the column headers of the old DB into it. You can then do something like this (whereas the following code assumes you have overwritten the headers instead of inserting a line above, so you might have to adapt this)

```
Sub compare()

    'Lots of vars...
    Dim shtOld As Worksheet, shtNew As Worksheet
    Dim keyOld As Range, keyNew As Range
    Dim rOld As Range, rNew As Range
    Dim colOld As Range, colNew As Range
    Dim numColsOld As Integer, numColsNew As Integer, i As Integer, k As Integer

    'Set
    Set shtOld = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set shtNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    numColsOld = shtOld.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    numColsNew = shtNew.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Loop column B of old DB
    For k = 1 To shtOld.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        Set keyOld = shtOld.Range("B" & k + 1)

        'Find key in other sheet (assuming key is always in B, 
        'else do a column search here as well, see below)
        Set keyNew = shtNew.Range("B:B").Find(keyOld.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not keyNew Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Found key at: " & keyNew.Address

            'Loop Cols
            For i = 1 To numColsOld
                Set colOld = shtOld.Cells(1, i) 'starting from A, the first to the left
                'Find column header in New
                Set colNew = shtNew.Range("A1:" & Cells(1, numColsNew).Address).Find(colOld.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not colNew Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "Found Column at: " & colNew.Column

                    Set rOld = shtOld.Cells(keyOld.Row, colOld.Column)
                    Set rNew = shtNew.Cells(keyNew.Row, colNew.Column)

                    If rOld <> rNew Then rNew.Interior.ColorIndex = 24

                End If
                Set newcol = Nothing
            Next i

        End If
        Set newkey = Nothing

    Next k

    'Cleanup
    Set rOld = Nothing
    Set rNew = Nothing
    Set shtOld = Nothing
    Set shtNew = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this vba module into a VBscript. I have a very bleak idea about all this.

Comment: Sorry, missed the script part. Why can't you do it from within Excel?

Comment: I got my direction :) Thanks Ronald

Comment: Ronald any ideas on how to do mapping except array?

Comment: As I wrote: insert the row and do the name mapping there. Else use an Excel table and do a .Find there, too